# Why can't a public body exercise its powers for any purpose allowed by the empowering statute?

Tags: england-and-wales

In this [online multiple choice question](https://learninglink.oup.com/access/content/faragher-concentrate6e-resources/faragher-concentrate6e-chapter-11-self-test-questions?previousFilter=tag_chapter-11), I picked the last choice. I agree that the first choice is true, but why's the last one wrong?

[image]

Comment: The posted answer has it, I think. It’s a question about statutory interpretation requiring multiple choice answer interpretation! Like, imagine a friend gives you their credit card and asks you to pick them up something from the store. There’s no reason for you to think that because you are allowed to go buy item X, you’re *also* allowed to go buy items Y and Z. Finally, a good rule of thumb for questions like this, where you just don’t know if it could be between two... an answer that contains always, never, every, etc is almost certainly the wrong one. Never be so certain!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Break it down then take it to an absurd extreme to prove a point:

HMRC exercises its powers to collect PAYE tax

For the purposes to fund the NHS and to pay for all its employees to have a free hair cut once the current lockdown has been lifted

One of which is allowed by [statute](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/2003/1/contents) (PAYE not hair cuts)

Comment: The free hair cuts might be a public health measure to combat Cholera, Typhoid fever and other 1900 "contagious diseases"

Comment: I'm thinking more about the here-and-now. I last had my haircut in 2019 BC (that's *Before Covid*) and I'm starting to look like it's the 70's all over again - if you weren't around then it was an eclectic mix of Farrah Flicks, mullets and mohecans.